# Getting Android SDK version of a device from command line

Tags: android, shell, sdk, version

I'm planning to build an automated system for deploying an Android build to various devices, in order to make development for multiple platforms a bit more comfortable. Is there a way to get the sdk version of a connected device through android shell or adb?

There will be a computer to which several test devices is connected, and I was planning to write a script which will fetch the correct build for each of those from a build-server, install the different apks on their respective devices, launch them and collect log info, to be made available through some other program whose specifications are beside the point.

The point is that I need to know the sdk version each device is running to install the correct apk, and I was hoping I could get this through adb, but I can't seem to find a way to access it short of building a tiny app, compatible with all versions, whose sole purpose would be to output android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK or similar somewhere my script could read it.

Comment: Thanks to both Tim and Tor-Morten; sorry about the late reply, it's been hectic for some weeks. ro.build.version.sdk suited my needs just fine :) Tim gets the accept because his phrasing was better suited to running from a script to get the value.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

you can use this command:

```
adb shell grep ro.build.version.sdk= system/build.prop
```

It will output something like this:

```
ro.build.version.sdk=10
```

Comment: Some older android phones do not have "grep", but you can do this instead: ```adb shell cat system/build.prop | grep ro.build.version.sdk=```

Comment: @AlexFlint: they don't have grep but I can use `... | grep ...`?

Comment: @ThomasWeller The difference is whether to run the grep command on the device or on your computer.

Answer (score 35):

```
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
```

Note @Tim: this works even on phones without `grep` support on all host OS :-). (i.e. on old phones where `toolbox` does not support `grep` you you need to have `busybox` on your phone).

Comment: if you happen to be running an emulator as well as a physical device, you can use `adb devices` then use the serial number in the command above too.  i.e. `adb -s [yourSerial] shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk`

Comment: @Kelton.Temby yep, I often use `-s serial` as I have often connected more than one phone. Also `ANDROID_SERIAL` can be used to specify phone serial id.

Answer (score 6):

I also discovered a way to get the exact version of Android e.g. 4.2.2 based on the following web article http://xayon.net/looking-for-android-version-with-adb/ You need to be using a unix-like operating system - Linux and Mac OSX are fine, and windows users can use cygwin or equivalent.

At a command line:

`echo version=$(adb shell getprop |awk -F":" '/build.version.release/ { print $2 }')|tr -d '[]'`

Here is the result for my Nexus 4:

`version= 4.2.2`

Answer (score 3):

I think you can by accessing the device with adb shell - change directories to position you at system and do a cat of build.prop. Here you will find for instance, ro.build.description=google_sdk-eng 2.2, ro.build.version.release=2.2 etc