# Android can't run UI Testing with "uiautomator: permission denied" error message

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

My environment is:

Android phone : HTC Desired Z

Android version: 2.3.3

when i use the web method:http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html

run the UI Testing with the command "adb shell uiautomator runtest LaunchSettings.jar -c com.uia.example.my.LaunchSettings"

it show the error message "uiautomator: permission denied" .

Anyone friend that tell me to the reason of error???

thank!~

Comment: Are you running the original firmware from the manufacturer? Or have you loaded a ROM mod onto your device?

Comment: Yes, i run the original firmware from the manufacturer. it have been load a rom mod onto my device.

Comment: @DanielHsu, did you manage to run the UI test on v2.3.3? Could you pls, share how. While click the Snapshot button on the uiautomatorview  I got error "uiautomator requires device running api level 16". I have connected a device running v2.3.6 and sdk api v17 is installed on dev system.

Answer (score 2):

Can you double-check a couple of things please?

- Which version of Android are you deploying the tests to? UIAutomator is only available on devices with API level 16 or later (Android 4.1 and 4.2) so it should not be available on a 2.3.3 device. Run the following command on a command-line to get the version of Android installed: `adb shell grep ro.build.version.sdk= system/build.prop` the result should be similar to `ro.build.version.sdk=17` Here is a StackOverflow article on getting the version of Android using adb shell [Getting Android SDK version of a device from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063461/getting-android-sdk-version-of-a-device-from-command-line)
- What is the precise error message do you get when you run the `adb shell uiautomator runtest LaunchSettings.jar -c com.uia.example.my.LaunchSettings` command?

I tested with an AVD running 2.3.3 (API level 10) and ran the commands to build, deploy and then run the UI Automator tests from the Android example from http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html  The error message I get is different from the one you report: I get `uiautomator: not found` rather than `permission denied`.

As a suggestion, try to run `uiautomatorviewer` from the command line when your device is connected (which you can check with the `adb devices` command - your device's serial number should be listed). When I run uiautomatorviewer against the AVD with 2.3.3 when I try to get a screen snapshot it tells me explicitly "UI Automator requires a device with API Level 16"

So in summary, AFAIK you need uiautomator with a device running API level 16 or later. In practice, UI Automator seems to be problematic on API level 16 (Android 4.1) and works best with devices running 4.2.1 of Android (API level 17).

Comment: Daniel, I cannot see your command :( However, I'm actually more interested in the exact error message you get after running your command. Also, can you run the following command from the command line and add the result here? `adb shell grep ro.build.version.sdk= system/build.prop` The answer should be similar to `ro.build.version.sdk=17` - the final number will depend on which version of Android you have installed on your device.

Comment: @JulianHarty, as you have mentioned you had tested it on AVD running 2.3.3. Have you tried it on real device running 2.3.3? I am getting an error "uiautomator requires device running api level 16", though have api level 17 on the dev system. The [android doc](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html#uianalysis) says it requires SDK Tools v21 or higher and Platform SDK API v16 or higher. But nothing about device version. can it be done on devices running below api v16?

Comment: Dexter, I believe the device needs the same minimum version of the platform SDK i.e. v16 or later. I believe I only tried using older versions of Android to help understand the problem that was being reported. I didn't expect it to work i.e. I didn't and still don't expect UI Automator to work on any device running 2.x of Android.